# php write not writing the first time

Tags: jquery, ajax, post, fwrite

I am saving some data in localstorage variabes and would like to write those to a file created with PHP.

In my html page I have a function called updatesurvey.

This function is doing the following:

```
    var newdate = new Date();
    var q1age = localStorage.getItem('age');
    var q2gender1 = localStorage.getItem('gender1');
    var q2gender2 = localStorage.getItem('gender2');

                    function updatesurvey(){ 

                        $.ajax({
                          url: "save2file.php",
                          type: "post",
                          data: "&date="+newdate+"&Q1="+q1age+"&Q2_1="+q2gender1+"&Q2_2="+q2gender2+,
                          success: function(){
                              // alert("Thank you");
                          },
                          error:function(){
                              // alert("Sorry");
                          }   
                          }); 
                    };
```

In the save2file.php I want to write the POST data again to a file:

```
<?php
$writedate = $_POST["date"];
$writeQ1 = $_POST["Q1"];
$writeQ2_1 = $_POST["Q2_1"];
$writeQ2_2 = $_POST["Q2_2"];

$fp = fopen('surveydata.csv', 'a');

$data = "$writedate;$writeQ1;$writeQ2_1;$writeQ2_2".PHP_EOL;


fwrite($fp, $data);
fclose($fp);

?>
```

When I check my surveydata.csv file I have always a correct date.
The values for the other POST data is NULL.
However when I go back to the html page and call the action updatesurvey again (without entering new data) it writes the data correclty.

***So my surveydata.csv looks the first time like this:***

Sat Dec 12 2015 07:32:12 GMT 0100 (Central Europe Standard Time);**null;null;null**

***And the second time:***

Sat Dec 12 2015 07:35:48 GMT 0100 (Central Europe Standard Time);**A2;male;null**

Any idea what is going wrong?
Why is it only writing the date variable correct the first time and the other variables not?

Comment: Are you sure it's a problem on PHP side and not in your javascript code? Try alerting or logging the values before passing them to `$.ajax`.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution.
This was just my mistake.

I have moved

```
var newdate = new Date();
var q1age = localStorage.getItem('age');
var q2gender1 = localStorage.getItem('gender1');
var q2gender2 = localStorage.getItem('gender2');
```

After:

```
                function updatesurvey(){
```

Now it all is working.